# Uninstall Glassfish and metro completely

Tags: java, glassfish

I thought of updating my Glassfish server from 2.1 to 3.1.1 in a **Linux** machine. I downloaded the .ZIP package.

However during uninstalling of Glassfish v2.1 I did not find the uninstall.sh file in "bin" directory.

Following are a few steps which I did...

1. I removed the glassfish folder (rm -rf ...)
2. After removing files in the end it gave me a notification that it could not remove 2 files used by Metro. I cant recollect those file names, but I manually deleted that folder.
3. I made a mistake by first not uninstalling Metro.
4. I uninstalled metro completely after that. but it seemed pointless (it uninstalled successfully :P )
5. I transfered the Glassfish 3.1.1 ZIP file and unzipped and configured it.

FOllow are a few Problems I am facing

1. I cannot deploy any of my WAR file. Its giving errors saying " Error creating bean,Instantiation of bean failed etc etc." (However the WAR file is getting deployed successfully in other Linux Machine)
2. When I try installing Metro v2.1 separately, it does not show the admin console or it timesout while starting the domain.
3. The **Log File** of the Domain says it has started the domain successfully and the process is also created. But after running the command (asadmin) it takes like forever and times out without showing Domain Started Successfully,

There is no uninstall.sh in Glassfishv3.1.1 bin directory.

How do I completely uninstall Glassfish v 3.1.1 and Metro 2.1 ??? What are the files which I will have to manually remove?